# Jquery UI Tabs & jcarousel lite pluings does not seem to work (conflict) in Internet Explorer (IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jcarousellite

I've both the jquery-UI Tabs & [jcarousel lite plugin](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/demo.php) in my webpage, all works good in all browsers apart from IE where i assume there's some sort of conflict as if i take out the jcarousel JS then the tabs works fine.

Has anyone got any suggestion on this issue or how to fix it? Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tabs > ul').tabs({ 
        fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } 
    }); 

    $("#carousel").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".prev",
        btnPrev: ".next",
        visible: 4,
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out is was simply the comma at the end of "visible: 4," needed to be taken out.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](http://i.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png))</sub>  Nise Code for jquery

$(function() {

$(".mouseWheel .jCarouselLite").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: ".mouseWheel .next",
    btnPrev: ".mouseWheel .prev",
    easing: "easeinout",
    visible: 4,
    mouseWheel: true
});

});

$(function() {
    $(".anyClass2").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next2",
        btnPrev: ".prev2"
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

I put the above javascript into http://javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php - here's a snippet of the results

```
10                  btnPrev: ".next",
11                  visible: 4,
12          });
    ========^
    warning: trailing comma is not legal in ECMA-262 object initializers
```